# How to prevent 2 objects from splitting on top of another

Tags: javascript

Hello so Im creating a game (since i recently started studying javascript). The game is Asteroids the code is basically the same as freeCodeCamp video only some differences are the scoring system storing and music/sounds. However I want to prevent of 2 objects(asteroids) from spawning/splitting on top of another (If i split the asteroid it spawns the splits in one another) I want to make sure that splitting is more relistic since now they spawn on each other. This is the code I use to split them and the variables i have

```
function destroyAsteroid(index) {
            var x = roids[index].x;
            var y = roids[index].y;
            var r = roids[index].r;
          
            if (r == Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 2)) { 
                roids.push(newAsteroid(x, y, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)));
                roids.push(newAsteroid(x, y, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)));
                score += ROID_PTS_LGE;
            } else if (r == Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)) { 
                roids.push(newAsteroid(x, y, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 8)));
                roids.push(newAsteroid(x, y, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 8)));
                score += ROID_PTS_MED;
            } else {
                score += ROID_PTS_SML;
```

what would be easiest way to make them spawn next to each other rather then on top of one another.

I havent tried most of the things the only things i tried is getting a distance between the points(2 split asteroids and then using if function to check if the distance between them is the size of the asteroid size

Comment: `what would be easiest way to make them spawn next to each other rather then on top of one another.` Maybe don't give them the same x/y values?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like `newAsteroid` function accepts X and Y coordinates as its first two parameters. Why not give different values for the asteroids that you want to place next to each other?

You can calculate the coordinates as something like that:

```
const x1 = x + r;
const y1 = y + r;
const x2 = x - r;
const y2 = y - r;
```

And then use these values to push new asteroids:

```
if (r == Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 2)) { 
    roids.push(newAsteroid(x1, y1, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)));
    roids.push(newAsteroid(x2, y2, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)));
    score += ROID_PTS_LGE;
} else if (r == Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 4)) { 
    roids.push(newAsteroid(x1, y1, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 8)));
    roids.push(newAsteroid(x2, y2, Math.ceil(ROID_SIZE / 8)));
    score += ROID_PTS_MED;
} else {
    score += ROID_PTS_SML;
```

This should place asteroids along the diagonal line, if `r` is the radius.

**By the way**, seems strange to me that asteroids are spawning in a function called `destroyAsteroid`!  I see, this is called like that because 'to destroy' means 'to split' the asteroid in two pieces.